# Java Eclipse Connect to MySQL via Tomcat

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, tomcat, vaadin

How to connect Tomcat9 to a MySQL database and access the database in eclipse using Vaadin14? I already pasted the mysql connector in the tomcat\lib directory. Is there anything else to do/change?

Afterwards i created a ui that contains a few text fields and a java class car with some attributes and the corresponding getters/setters. I bound the text fields  to the attributes using a binder. In my database there is also a table car with the same attributes and some entries. 
So how do i connect the database to my project in order to show one of the entries in my text fields and create a new entry?
Sorry if this is basic java/vaadin, but i'm quite new to databases.

Comment: I know how to show create/show an entry, just want to know how to get a connection to the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So how do i connect the database to my project in order to show one of the entries in my text fields and create a new entry

- You first need to connect to a database. It depends on your project, how you implement it. (via Spring, for example). A good discussion on this topic is here: [Connect Java to a MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/connect-java-to-a-mysql-database)
   and some documentation here [Connecting to MySQL Using the JDBC DriverManager Interface](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html)
- Then you read data you need from a database. You can use ORM such as [Hibernate](https://hibernate.org/orm/documentation/5.4/) or use a JDBC package as this. A discussion on pros/cons can be found here: [What Java ORM do you prefer, and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452385/what-java-orm-do-you-prefer-and-why)
- Once you have your data available, you can bind an object to the binder (if you use one) or using `setValue` for the fields. There is an example for Vaadin 8 here : [Building a web UI for MySQL databases (in plain Java)](https://vaadin.com/blog/building-a-web-ui-for-mysql-databases-in-plain-java-), but it should be applicable with a Vaadin 14 as well. (Or what is your version?)
- You could also check a [bakery starter](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/bakeryflow/overview.html) and how connection/reading is implemented there.

Some other useful links on topic:

- [What is JPA? Introduction to the Java Persistence API](https://www.javaworld.com/article/3379043/what-is-jpa-introduction-to-the-java-persistence-api.html)
- [Vaadin app with MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47490002/vaadin-app-with-mysql-database)